# SIM808 module does not get GPS location

Tags: gps, sim

I am trying to use a SIM808 module to get a GPS location, but it does not work. My power supply can provide up to 5A. The picture results from my communication with the SIM module using the AT command. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a problem acquiring the GPS signals. Antenna connected correctly? Indoors or outdoors?

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead

Comment: antenna exactly connected, outdoor antenna @MarkLeavitt